# Returning a odata 4 error in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData

During a patch operation we validate that there is no duplicates in the system and if so I want to return a 400 to the client with a correctly formatted [Odata 4 error](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793091)

Such as

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, [FromBody] Delta<User> patch)
{
  return BadRequest("Duplicate email address");
}
```

I am expecting the json body to be

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "400",
    "message": "Duplicate email address"
  }
}
```

However I receive

```json
{
  "@odata.context":"https://localhost:3200/odata/$metadata#Edm.String",
  "value":"Duplicate email address"
}
```

Comment: Hi @JProgrammer,any updates about this case?

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu yep worked as described thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like below:

```
var statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return BadRequest(new ODataError { ErrorCode = statusCode.ToString(), Message = "Duplicate email address" });
```

Result:
[image]